# Linux shell select files in directory and subdirectiry

Tags: linux, bash, glob

For selecting all php files in a folder , we use :

```
vim *.php
```

How to use this command for selecting *.php files in this directory and his subdirectories ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With shell option `globstar`` in bash you can use

```
vim **/*.php
```

To enable the shell option use e.g.

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Comment: It works fine, great !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` combined with `xargs`:

```sh
find . -type f -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 vi
```

The `find` will locate all regular files matching `*.php`, in and below the current directory, and send all the names in a stream to `xargs` separated by `NUL` characters.

The `xargs` program (with a `-0` matching the `-print0`) will then separate them into individual file names and pass as many as possible to a single `vi` invocation. If it can't fit them all in one invocation (unlikely, unless the number of files is truly massive), it will make multiple invocations as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [brace expansions](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion):

```
vim {,*/}*.php
```

### How does it work

- `{,*/}` expands to `<empty> dir1/ dir2/ ...`
- the final command line is then: `ls *.php dir1/*.php dir2/*.php ...`

This only matches immediate subdirectories, so subdirectories of a subdirectory won't be included.  As mentioned in the other answeres, `find` or `globstar` is better suited for that.